# php/mysql database searching

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone see why the code below is not working?  Is it because of the deprecated sql syntax?  I'm stumped with this one.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);  
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$usersearch=$_POST['search'];
$query="SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE 'artist' LIKE '%$usersearch%'";  
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result); 

mysql_close();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

echo $row["artist"]." | ".$row["name"];
echo "<br>";

}  

?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you checked your error log? What errors do you get? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this?

Comment: First of all, don't use '@', it's a bad practice. Also, please specify, what output you get. Have you tried print_r($row);? what does it say? Finally, yes, mysql_ is deprecated, but it still works though

Comment: John, it's for a school project - i know it doesn't work because when i type a listed artist from the database into the searchbox it just returns a blank page.  What's an error log?

Comment: Since you found your answer, please mark it as accepted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

**First, do not use mysql_* please. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

You can use [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Answer (score 1):

Probably beacuse you have single quotes(') and not ` when selecting your table. And as pointed out don't use mysql_* use PDO or mysqli, even if its just a school project(old habits die hard). Also you could add

```
mysql_query($query) or die($mysql_error());
```

This will probably point out whats wrong..

and for last, please escape dynamic input variables

Comment: sgulseth - you fixed it!! it was the quote marks around artist - i have taken them out and its searching, many many thanks EVERYONE for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

add to the top of page:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

and open the page in an browser. are there any errors?

change (this mutes errors)

```
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

to :

```
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

A word of advice though, better to use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [PDO_MySQL][3] instead of `mysql_connect`since it will soon be deprecated:

> **Warning**
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_connect()

you can find more info of how to use them on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329447/examples-of-small-php-and-my-sql-projects-to-learn-the-basics/12329478#12329478).

**UPDATE**

check if you get an empty result, add :

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result); 
if ($num === 0) echo "Empty result"
```

and open the page again. if the page is still blank, change:

```
echo $row["artist"]." | ".$row["name"];
echo "<br>";
```

to:

```
vardump($row);
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you did get `Empty result`, than add

```
echo $query;
```

and try to open the page and run the query manually

Comment: Thanks, i've made the changes - no reported errors - just a white screen

Comment: Kuf, i don't know which php version it's on a school server?  I am getting an empty result returned?

Comment: sorry, i don't follow, did you get "Empty result"?

Comment: Still completely blank after vardump